# Changing chart type give: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am initially loading the chart in **candlestick** mode.

Then on click of a button changing it to **line** mode.

Both candlestick and line chart data has different data point

```
candlestick = [[datetime, open, high, low, close], ....]
line = [[datetime, close], ....]
```

On click of a button

```
    if (requiredType == "candlestick") {
        chart.series[seriesindex].update({
            type: "candlestick",
            keys: ['x', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'],
            data: candlestick,
        }, true);

    } else if (requiredType == "line") {
        chart.series[seriesindex].update({
            type: "line",
            keys: ['x', 'y'],
            data: line,
        }, true);
    }
```

Initially the chart is loaded in **candlestick** mode.
Upon clicking the change type button it fails and gives the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.high (highstock.src.js:47746)
    at v.ohlc (highstock.src.js:47764)
    at v.l (highstock.src.js:47865)
    at v.t.processData (highstock.src.js:48205)
    at v.F.processData (highstock.src.js:53103)
    at highstock.src.js:16601
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at G.setTickInterval (highstock.src.js:16600)
    at G.setScale (highstock.src.js:16936)
    at highstock.src.js:24043
high    @   highstock.src.js:47746
ohlc    @   highstock.src.js:47764
l   @   highstock.src.js:47865
t.processData   @   highstock.src.js:48205
F.processData   @   highstock.src.js:53103
(anonymous) @   highstock.src.js:16601
setTickInterval @   highstock.src.js:16600
setScale    @   highstock.src.js:16936
(anonymous) @   highstock.src.js:24043
redraw  @   highstock.src.js:24041
update  @   highstock.src.js:34110
toggleChart @   fno.js:336
(anonymous) @   fno.js:907
dispatch    @   jquery.js:4435
r.handle    @   jquery.js:4121
```

But if initially I load the chart in line mode and then switch to candlestick mode then it wont fail but leaves the chart empty without drawing anything.

And also if I just have very few points on the chart like say 10 point and the chart is in candlestick mode and i switch it to line mode then it works fine, but with more data say mode than 500 point it wont work.

Comment: Hi @maharshi, I tried to reproduce the problem, but everything seems to work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6j1vhtac/ Could you adapt that example to show the issue?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek I for the same code increase the data to 500 and click on *All*. It dose'nt work. http://jsfiddle.net/x1ckz2pw/ ( also edited my question which says 150 to 500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also update `approximation`, which is by default set to `'average'` for `line` series and `'ohlc'` for `ohlc` series.

```
$('#line').on('click', function() {
    chart.series[0].update({
        type: 'line',
        dataGrouping: {
            approximation: 'average'
        },
        keys: ['x', 'y'],
        data: line
    });
});

$('#candlestick').on('click', function() {
    chart.series[0].update({
        type: 'candlestick',
        dataGrouping: {
            approximation: 'ohlc'
        },
        keys: ['x', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'],
        data: candlestick
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qh7wLc94/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.ohlc.dataGrouping.approximation